# Ping local network from wired to wireless is not working

Tags: networking, ping

Why can't each computer ping each other in the same network and both firewalls are completely turned off?

First computer is connected through wired. Second computer is connected through wireless.

Ping works fine if i use wired connection for the second computer. But I want to use wireless for the second only. How should I resolve this?

SETUP:
I am using an5506-04-fg as my router, connected a UTP cable from LAN1 to TP-LINK 8-port fast ethernet switch (TL-SF1008D), port 1. My wired computer is connected at port 2. Internet connection works fine. My second computer is connected, WIFI connection, to the router.

IPConfig on 1st computer:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ad68:a005:6599:fe5%13
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.12
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

IPConfig on 2nd computer:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c042:fc0a:2d7a:37b6%14
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.11
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Obviously something is blocking the ping when the second computer is wireless. However, without more information about your network, all we can do is guess. How is your network configured? What router/wireless access point are you using? Can other wireless devices be pinged?

Comment: I have updated my question. maybe that's enough?

Comment: Much better. Look in your router for any settings that would restrict traffic from wireless clients in any way. Also, just to confirm, you can't ping computer 1 from 2, nor 2 from 1?

Comment: ok will check for possible restriction in my router. Yes you're right, can't ping on both direction computer 1 to 2 and vice versa.

Comment: You may want to disable IGMP Snooping in your router.

Answer (score 0):

My answer has been converted to a comment. Anyway my answer is: You've got to disable the IGMP snooping feature of your router.